# Self Executing functions as properties of object literals

Tags: javascript, object-literal, uglifyjs, self-executing-function

I'm minifying some code using UglifyJs and i'm having a problem.  If I have a self executing function as a property of an object literal, on minification it's reduced to a function.

i.e.

```
var o = {
    c : 1,
    t : (function(){
        return 'this worked';
    }())
};

uglifyjs t.js > u.js

var o={c:1,t:function(){return"this worked"}()};
```

Presumably there is a reason why this way of doing things is not recommended.  What/why is this? and also if there's a work around I would love to know, as the client code would rather use a property.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the function is executed - you have `()` after its definition.

Comment: I don't see any problem, drop this in the console: `(o={c:1,t:function(){return"this worked"}()}).t`.

Comment: It's still immediately-executing -- the parentheses around the function definition in the original code were redundant, uglify removed them to minify it more.

Comment: thanks kobi. Missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returned the same self executing function without the surrounding brackets... so I don't see the problem...

As a note, JSON doesn't support functions declared in it's content. You can use it, since it's still javascript code, but you cannot serialize it... etc.